# Should I avoid using WP with some sort of visual composer when hosting on my Rapberry Pi 4? Is there a better and equally easy approach?

Tags: pi-4, memory, database, wordpress

I've been told a WP-install can easily consume 2 Gigs of memory when editing in visual composers in WP. When my Pi only has 4 GB available and on top on that I'm running MariaDB (NOT Nginx), then there really shouldn't be much RAM left for anything else should there?

Or did I get bad advise and is WP perfectly capable of running fast on efficiently on MariaDB and an RPi 4 ?

And if not: What is there of better alternatives to running a webserver on a PI? Preferably a CMS of some sort.

Comment: *MariaDB (NOT Nginx)* ... so you're running a database not a web server? - you still need a web server

Comment: No I have it All running right now on https://it.sucks.dk - wp installed snd everything. But I have heard rumours about Nginx being much faster for use theman MariaDB - is this true? I really meant with my my last question: is CMS too much for the Pi too handle efficiently or is there an alternstive CMS it will load really fast?

Comment: again, you seem to be comparing a http server (nginx) with a database (mariadb)

Comment: I am I can see that.. I dodnt mean mariaDB I meant apache2 :-D sorry for the confusion... (Been doing this all day)

Comment: So: is nginx faster and better then apache for the rpi 4?

Comment: yes, use nginx instead of apache  - but that's just personal opinion. Also not sure if WP is written such that it actually needs apache specifically - how about you try it and see which works better - there is also `lighttpd` which, as you can tell from the name, claims to be a light (on resources) http server - though it doesn't have as many "features" as apache or nginx, but not sure if the lacking features are required for WP, again, give it a go, see what happens

Comment: I tried nginx once but failed some time after I got it to work.. dont know how it stopped working, maybe I dod something wrong. Will try nginx - thx. Edit: do you know any CMS which is lighter to run than WP? It doesn't need to have many extensions.

Comment: I know of nothing beyond the google results for `lightweight CMS`

Comment: Kudo for pointing out my lazyness in googling it myself. This thred can be closed now I think :)

Comment: @ITBlacksmith "*This thread can be closed now I think.*", I think it would be helpful if you test and tell the summary on an answer here. Others could read your answers and findings. || In addition, try `google` => `online website analysis tool`. There is a lot of website in this case and you can get a statistic of your site. In [this link](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/it.sucks.dk/ePxrdFd7) I have tested your site. Check the result. The size is too large and the load time is kind of awful.

Comment: "*Is nginx faster and better than apache for the rpi 4?*", [The official raspberry pi site ](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress) suggests LAMP which is **L**inux, **A**pache, **M**ySQL, **P**HP.

Comment: THANK you @M. Rostami - that's exacctly the kind of answer and tools I was hoping to get - now I can try something out and  get back to you when I has improven on my load time for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Google it: `online website analysis tool`. There is a lot of website in this case and you can get a statistic of your site. In [this link](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/it.sucks.dk/ePxrdFd7), I have tested your site. Check the result. The size is too large and the load time is kind of awful.

---

> Is nginx faster and better than apache for the rpi 4?

[The official raspberry pi website](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress) suggests LAMP which is Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP.