# Is the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B a fast web hosting server for a single website?

Tags: web-server, wordpress

I'm thinking of purchasing a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B to host my WordPress website. The website has 4 pages and 2-3 plugins. Will it be fast?

Here are some specs for the Raspberry:

Broadcom BCM2711, quad-core Cortex-A72 (ARM v8) 64-bit SoC @ 1.5GHz 1GB LPDDR4-2400 SDRAM 2.4GHz and 5.0 GHz IEEE 802.11b/g/n/ac wireless LAN, Bluetooth 5.0, BLE True Gigabit Ethernet

Comment: I would think the expected traffic is the major question, how many simultaneous connections? In my experience the performance would be perfectly adequate for one or two connections at a time.

Comment: You forgot an important detail: how fast is the storage drive? That's important for a web host, while Bluetooth is completely irrelevant for it. Will you be connecting it wirelessly to WiFi or with a wired Ethernet connection? That's important for stability.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your website and you should look for the size of that and its content. However, **after** the first model raspberry pi, it would be possible to run your website on a raspberry pi. Because the RAM capacity is reasonable and there would be no concentration about that.

It's all about your internet capacity and your storage. If you intended to use the default SD-Card as your database and store your site to that, you would face some problem. We suggest you add another drive like Flash Drive, HDD or SSD. Of course, the SSD is a choice without any question.

You might found some article about using `nginx` instead of `apache` but [the official raspberry pi website](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress) suggests LAMP which is **L**inux, **A**pache, **M**ySQL, **P**HP.

After all, you can check your website performance by an online website analyzer like [gtmetrix.com](https://gtmetrix.com/) that you can acquire statistics of your site.

---

- [A More Secure Wordpress Setup for Raspberry Pi](https://samhobbs.co.uk/2014/07/more-secure-wordpress-setup-raspberry-pi)
- [Install WordPress on a Raspberry Pi (with Nginx)](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/install-wordpress-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-nginx/)
- [Hosting LAMP on SD-card in RPi now - would like to move whole database and website to External USB 3.0 SSD](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108130/hosting-lamp-on-sd-card-in-rpi-now-would-like-to-move-whole-database-and-websi)
- [Will SD-card in an RPi 4 always be faster than USB 3.0 writing/reading to an installed web-server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107977/will-sd-card-in-an-rpi-4-always-be-faster-than-usb-3-0-writing-reading-to-an-ins)
- [Should I avoid using WP with some sort of visual composer when hosting on my Raspberry Pi 4? Is there a better and equally easy approach?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107460/should-i-avoid-using-wp-with-some-sort-of-visual-composer-when-hosting-on-my-rap)